# Group array elements and show total

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to group same element values in an array and then display its total at the end of the array group. I can display the array group count as it goes up but I only want to display the final total at the end something like the following;

### Desired Output

A 
Same Info 
Same Info 
Same Info 
Total 4 
B 
Same Info 
Same Info 
Same Info 
Same Info 
Total 5

### Output

A 
1 
Same Info 
2 
Same Info 
3 
Same Info 
4 
B 
1 
Same Info 
2 
Same Info 
3 
Same Info 
4 
Same Info 
5

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = "A";
$arr[] = "A";
$arr[] = "A";
$arr[] = "A";
$arr[] = "B";
$arr[] = "B";
$arr[] = "B";
$arr[] = "B";
$arr[] = "B";
$f = "";

$total = 0;

foreach ($arr as $a) 
{
$c = $a;
if ($c != $f) {
            $f = $c;

            $total = 1;

            echo $a . "<br>";
        } else {
            $total++;

            echo 'Same Info <br>';
        }

        echo $total . "<br>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you need this code . I added a condition before showing the $total, the condition is that the next element is different from the current or when the next element doesn't existe

```
   foreach ($arr as $key => $a) 
   {
      $c = $a;
      if ($c != $f) 
      {
         $f = $c;
         $total = 1;
         echo $a . "<br>";
      } 
      else 
      {
         $total++;
         echo 'Same Info <br>';
      }
      if(isset($arr[$key+1])&&$arr[$key+1]!=$a || !isset($arr[$key+1]))
         echo "Total " .  $total . "<br>";
   }
```

to test if the next element exists, I've added on the foreach look the `$key` and the next element in each iteration is the `$arr[$key+1]`